# Windows print spooler limitations?

Tags: windows, printing, spool

Is there a limit on how many print jobs can be queued up in the Windows Print Spooler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: There seems to be a 4GB Limit per Job, couldnt find any Info on other limitations, however. My own testing shows that it can handle a thousand Print Jobs/40kB without Problems.

Comment: I'm having troubles over 100 print jobs put through to the a label printer. This are placed by C# code. I'm wondering how I could code to 'wait' after 'a number' of jobs as to let it clear up..

Comment: The most obvious solution would be to Thread.Sleep() a little.

Answer (score -1):

If you put in a print job you want to cancel or is deleting but never actually leaves the queue do this:

1. Browse to Start>Run (click Window button + R) and type NET STOP SPOOLER and click enter.
2. Do the same thing but this time type NET START SPOOLER to restart the print spooler service.

Then you're able to start printing again.

Comment: that's not what I had been asking for.